In Crystal Reports I have a Parameter field + 2 years
In Crystal Reports I have a Parameter field for the user to enter the issued date (IssuedDate?) I'd like to create a formula field to add 2 years to this date as an expiration date.
I tried: DateAdd('yyyy',2,(IssuedDate?))

Change the parameter type to Date (instead of String).
Or convert it from string to date using the cDate() function.

Change
DateAdd('yyyy',2,(IssuedDate?))

to
DateAdd('yyyy',2,{IssuedDate?})

In future posts, consider revealing what the problem is (e.g. the error message you received).

Those are the bracets actually that I have in the formula but it highlights the parameter field and said a date is expected here.
